# Cannot get Composer for PHP to work in Win8

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I installed the Composer for PHP application on my Windows 8 laptop, and I am trying to run

```
composer.phar install
```

from CMD where the current directory is the project-folder of my XAMPP-server.
In this folder I have a file called:

```
composer.json
```

With this content:

```
{
"require" {
    "zurb/foundation": "v4.3.*"
    }

}
```

Then I am asked, by Windows, what program I would like to run PHAR-files with...
So, I chose php.exe from the XAMPP-server installation.

Then I get this output:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\playground1>composer.phar install
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version a2a70380c14a20b3f611d849eae7342f2e35c763 2013-10-21 09:51:22

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]

Options:
  --help           -h Display this help message.
  --quiet          -q Do not output any message.
  --verbose        -v|vv|vvv Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal ou
tput, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
  --version        -V Display this application version.
  --ansi              Force ANSI output.
  --no-ansi           Disable ANSI output.
  --no-interaction -n Do not ask any interactive question.
  --profile           Display timing and memory usage information
  --working-dir    -d If specified, use the given directory as working directory
.

Available commands:
  about            Short information about Composer
  archive          Create an archive of this composer package
  config           Set config options
  create-project   Create new project from a package into given directory.
  depends          Shows which packages depend on the given package
  diagnose         Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  dump-autoload    Dumps the autoloader
  dumpautoload     Dumps the autoloader
  global           Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER
_HOME).
  help             Displays help for a command
  init             Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  install          Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file
 if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  licenses         Show information about licenses of dependencies
  list             Lists commands
  require          Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs the
m
  run-script       Run the scripts defined in composer.json.
  search           Search for packages
  self-update      Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate       Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  show             Show information about packages
  status           Show a list of locally modified packages
  update           Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to
composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  validate         Validates a composer.json

c:\xampp\htdocs\playground1>
```

So, to me it seems that the Composer program doens't recognize that I have given it some parameters to work with... what could be the mistake here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess while creating the connection between `.phar` files and `php` as the application to open these, Windows did not add code to pass further command line arguments. So PHP effectively only gets the name of the Phar file, and nothing else.

[I found this question](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with) which looks like the answer from Marcus Pope has the right solution: Add `%*` to the open command to pass all further cli options.

Comment: Thank's a lot! You know, I changed my OS to Manjaro Linux (shhh!) That solved all my problems :) Anyway, if I get back in Windows, then I have the solution from you!